# Tamanho de array dentro de um objeto

Tags: javascript, objetos

Olá , estou com duvida em como contabilizar os valores que se encontrar dentro de um array, que está em um objeto. Desde já agradecido pela ajuda.

```
 let spendin={
    recipes:[2000,5000,400],
    expenses:[8000]
}

function saldo(spendin){
    let x=0
    let limitex=spendin.recipes.length()
    let limitey=spendin.expenses.length()
    console.log(limitex)
    let somax,somay

        for(x=0;x<=limitex;x++){
            somax+=spendin.recipes[x]
        }
        for(x=0;x<=limitey;x++){
            somay+=spendin.recipes[x]
        }

    return somax-somay
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta está mal formulada, mas acho que consegui decifrar. Você quer calcular o total, somando as recipes e subtraindo as expenses, correto?

Para isso, o método reduce é seu melhor amigo. O método Reduce colapsa um array em um valor, usando uma lógica definida pela função que é passada para ele. Você pode procurar mais detalhes na documentação da MDN [aqui.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

O código para calcular o total seria mais ou menos assim:

```js
const spendin = {
    recipes: [2000, 5000, 400],
    expenses: [8000],
};

const getSaldo = spendin => {
    // calcula o total da receita
    const recipesTotal = spendin.recipes.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
    // calcula o total da despesa
    const expensesTotal = spendin.expenses.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
    return recipesTotal - expensesTotal;
};

console.log(getSaldo(spendin));
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, desculpa pela pergunta confusa, estou começando agora, estou bastante perdido ainda, mas muito obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Não peça desculpas por perguntar :) buscar conhecimento é sempre importante. Boa sorte em seu aprendizado